# MySQL - Combine SELECT and UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like MySQL to compare the values of 2 columns in a table. If both values are the same, an UPDATE-statement must be executed on another table. These are my 2 tables:

**TABLE**: EMPLOYEES

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME | CREDIT
---------------------------
     1      | John |   5
     2      | Bill |   10
     3      | Mark |   7
```

**TABLE**: BONUSES

```
BONUS_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | A | B | AMOUNT
---------------------------------------
    1    |      1      | x | x |   6
    2    |      2      | x | y |   19
    3    |      2      | y | x |   4
    4    |      3      | y | y |   12
    5    |      3      | x | x |   15
```

If in the bonuses-table the value of column A is equal to the value of column B, the "amount" value of that row must be added to the employees credit in the employees-table. In SQL, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bonuses WHERE A = B;
```

..and after that:

```
UPDATE employees SET credit = credit + bonuses.amount
```

-> For example:

In the "bonuses" table, the first row value A is euqal to value B. That means that the employee with EMPLOYEE_ID 1 (John) must have added 6 to their credit. The same goes for the 4th row where value A is equal to value B. In that case, the employee with EMPLOYEE_ID 3 (Mark) must have added 12 to their credit.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multiple-table update to join the tables:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES JOIN BONUSES USING (EMPLOYEE_ID)
SET    EMPLOYEES.CREDIT = EMPLOYEES.CREDIT + BONUSES.AMOUNT
WHERE  BONUSES.A = BONUSES.B
```

However, you may wish to consider whether this logic would be better implemented in a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER INSERT ON BONUSES FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.A = NEW.B THEN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET    CREDIT = CREDIT + NEW.AMOUNT
    WHERE  EMPLOYEE_ID = NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID
  END IF
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for a single row in the BONUSES-table. I edited the original question with an extra row in the BONUSES-table. Since the value of A is equal to value B in that row, EMPLOYEE_ID 3 (Mark) should have added 15 to his credit + 12 from the previous row, making a total of 34 in EMPLOYEES.CREDIT. But in your query, only 1 update per employee is executed by MySQL?

Comment: @elton73: Ah, good point.  You can instead join with a grouped subquery: `UPDATE EMPLOYEES JOIN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM BONUSES WHERE A=B GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID) t USING (EMPLOYEE_ID) SET EMPLOYEES.CREDIT = EMPLOYEES.CREDIT + t.AMOUNT`.

Comment: Your new query works perfectly now for all the rows.. you're a genius. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
update EMPLOYEE E 
inner join BONUSES B on
E.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND B.A = B.B
set E.CREDIT = E.CREDIT + B.AMOUNT;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your query has the same effect as eggyal's query. It only updates an employee's credit a single time, so in this case, the 5th row in the bonuses-table won't cause MySQL to update that employee a second time.. I would like MySQL to do that on every row where A is equal to B